# Laravel Elixir Browserify Failed!: Unexpected token - Using VueJs

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir

can anyone help me solving this problem? I'm trying to learn how to use Laravel's elixir.browserify + vue.js but I can't make this work! I'm getting this error:

```
gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Browserify Failed!: Unexpected token

D:\xampp\htdocs\pwebdev-project\resources\assets\js\components\skills.vue:1
<template>
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Any idea what could be the problem? Do I need to specify somehere that I want to use vueify or I just need to npm install it like I did?

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.13",
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.2.2",
    "vueify": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.11",
    "vue-resource": "^0.1.17"
  }
 }
```

gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('main.js');
});
```

main.js

```
var Vue = require('vue')
var Skills = require('./components/skills.vue')

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'skills' : Skills
    }
})
```

and /components/skills.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select v-model="skills_array" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option v-for="skill in list" value="@{{skill.id }}" >
                @{{ skill.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="skills" hidden v-model="skills_array">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created: function () {
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
                data.push({
                    'id': this.list[i].id,
                    'name': this.list[i].name,
                    'selected': false
                });
            }

            this.list = data;
            this.skills_array = [];
        },
        props: ['list', 'skills_array']
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some time looking around I found [this repo (JeffreyWay)](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-vueify) which states there is some lines I needed to add in my gulp file

Basically I needed this:

```
npm install laravel-elixir-vueify
```

And then in my gulpfile:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vueify');  ---> this line was missing

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('main.js');
});
```

I tought elixir was already compatible with vueify :/ I hope this helps anyone. Sorry for making whoever tried to help me waste your time.

Comment: I have the same problem but I had the line on my `gulpfile.js`. Any guess?

Comment: Note that for Elixir 5 and below, pull in v1.0.6, for Elixir 6 and up, just grab the latest v2.0 version. https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-vueify/issues/26

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is already so long ago but putting this code block in your `package.json` file will correctly compile it.

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify",
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
```

Now you can run again `gulp`

Comment: For some reason requiring *laravel-elixir-vueify* in my gulpfile was throwing an error, but your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're mixing up your templates and your Javascript code.

In `main.js`, you do this:

```
var Skills = require('./components/skills.vue')
```

`require` is intended to import Javascript modules so the code in one module can be used in another.  `components/skills.vue` is not a Javascript file, it's HTML. So the Javascript interpreter is choking on it.

You'll need to rewrite `skills.vue` to expose the Javascript. The HTML should (probably) be moved to a blade template - I say probably, because it appears you might be trying to use a Javascript templating system with Vue which is something I don't have much experience with (and I can't see any evidence of in the code you posted).

EDIT

I've never used `vueify` before, but my guess is that there's something missing in your `gulpfile.js` that should configure `vueify`.

For example, I write Coffeescript instead of Javascript and use `elixir` to browserify my Coffeescript. To get this to work right, I had to add some configuration to my gulpfile:

```
// add the coffeeify transform to the browserify stack
//
elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
    name: 'coffeeify',
    options: {}
});

// configure browserify to recognize the .coffee extension
//
elixir.config.js.browserify.options.extensions = ['.coffee'];

elixir(function(mix) { ... });
```

I'm guessing that you need to do something like my first config item above:

```
elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
    name: 'vueify',
    options: {}
});
```

This will instruct browserify to add vueify to it's stack of transformations.

You might also need to second option:

```
elixir.config.js.browserify.options.extensions = ['.vue'];
```

But I'm not sure about that. On my system, adding the `.coffee` extension allows me to refer to modules without the `.coffee` extension in my code. It doesn't appear you're doing that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess thats what vueify is supposed to do, check  https://github.com/vuejs/vueify 
I already checked around for some examples and as far as I searched I'm doing like everybody else xD https://github.com/vuejs/vueify-example

Comment: thanks man, you kinda directed me to the answer. I found this repo which explains what I needed to add to make vueify work
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-vueify